# Invalid Hook Call React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, runtime-error, hook

I keep on getting this error on my register screen. I would really appreciate it if you could let me know what the issue is. Thank you!

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https: //fb me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

````
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Dimensions, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Block, Button, Text, theme } from 'galio-framework';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import SafeView from '../components/SafeView';
import Form from '../components/Forms/Form';
import FormField from '../components/Forms/FormField';
import FormButton from '../components/Forms/FormButton';
import IconButton from '../components/IconButton';
import FormErrorMessage from '../components/Forms/FormErrorMessage';
import { registerWithEmail } from '../config/firebase';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('screen');
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string()
    .required()
    .label('Name'),
  email: Yup.string()
    .required('Please enter a valid email')
    .email()
    .label('Email'),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required()
    .min(6, 'Password must have at least 6 characters')
    .label('Password'),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string()
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Confirm Password must match Password')
    .required('Confirm Password is required')
});
const [passwordVisibility, setPasswordVisibility] = useState(true);
const [rightIcon, setRightIcon] = useState('eye');
const [confirmPasswordIcon, setConfirmPasswordIcon] = useState('eye');
const [confirmPasswordVisibility, setConfirmPasswordVisibility] = useState(true);
const [registerError, setRegisterError] = useState('');

function handlePasswordVisibility() {
  if (rightIcon === 'eye') {
    setRightIcon('eye-off');
    setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
  } else if (rightIcon === 'eye-off') {
    setRightIcon('eye');
    setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility);
  }
}

function handleConfirmPasswordVisibility() {
  if (confirmPasswordIcon === 'eye') {
    setConfirmPasswordIcon('eye-off');
    setConfirmPasswordVisibility(!confirmPasswordVisibility);
  } else if (confirmPasswordIcon === 'eye-off') {
    setConfirmPasswordIcon('eye');
    setConfirmPasswordVisibility(!confirmPasswordVisibility);
  }
}

async function handleOnSignUp(values, actions) {
  const { email, password } = values;
  try {
    await registerWithEmail(email, password);
  } catch (error) {
    setRegisterError(error.message);
  }
}

export default class Register extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <SafeView style={styles.container}>
        <Form
          initialValues={{
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: ''
          }}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={values => handleOnSignUp(values)}
        >
          <FormField
            name="name"
            leftIcon="account"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            autoFocus={true}
          />
          <FormField
            name="email"
            leftIcon="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            textContentType="emailAddress"
          />
          <FormField
            name="password"
            leftIcon="lock"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            secureTextEntry={passwordVisibility}
            textContentType="password"
            rightIcon={rightIcon}
            handlePasswordVisibility={handlePasswordVisibility}
          />
          <FormField
            name="confirmPassword"
            leftIcon="lock"
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            secureTextEntry={confirmPasswordVisibility}
            textContentType="password"
            rightIcon={confirmPasswordIcon}
            handlePasswordVisibility={handleConfirmPasswordVisibility}
          />
          <FormButton title={'Register'} />
          {<FormErrorMessage error={registerError} visible={true} />}
        </Form>
        <IconButton
          style={styles.backButton}
          iconName="keyboard-backspace"
          color={Colors.white}
          size={30}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </SafeView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 15,
  },
  backButton: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10
  }
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you are not using hooks correctly. Hooks need to be inside of a functional component. Currently, you are using them without a component. The only component you have here is a class component, so if you want to use hooks, you need to first convert it to a functional component, something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Register = (props) => {

  const [passwordVisibility, setPasswordVisibility] = useState(true);
  const [rightIcon, setRightIcon] = useState('eye');
  const [confirmPasswordIcon, setConfirmPasswordIcon] = useState('eye');
  const [confirmPasswordVisibility, setConfirmPasswordVisibility] = useState(true);
  const [registerError, setRegisterError] = useState('');

  // other component logic code here

  return (
    // your component rendering code here
  );
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing functional and class based components. React Hooks can only be used inside functional components. Convert your `Register` component into a functional component and move all the `useState` calls inside the component.